# Depend on test artifact of another project in Ivy (in sbt)

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

We are having trouble adding a test artifact from one third-party project to the Ivy `test` conf of another project.

We cannot express the following dependency: `myprj-common/test -> framework-app-base/test` using Ivy (in an sbt build).

Project `framework-app-base` has `src/main/scala`, which generates `jars/framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the Ivy repo 
and `src/test/scala`, which generates `tests/framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT-test.jar`

For instance, there is a utility class `/framework-app-base/src/test/scala/com/myco/fmwk/framework/base/test/util/TestUtility.scala`, which ends up in `${user.home}/.ivy2/repo/com.myco.fmwk.framework/framework-app-base/tests/framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT-test.jar`.

Our code from `myprj-common/src/test/scala` uses class `TestUtility`, and this works fine in the IDE.

When we try to run the sbt build (`sbt clean update compile test`), compilation works fine, but tests fail because `TestUtility` not found.

When we `show test:dependency-classpath` in sbt, we see that the main artifact is in the classpath, but the test artifact is not:

`jars/framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT.jar` is in the classpath

`tests/framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT-test.jar` is not in the classpath

We have tried specifying the dependency as shown below, but it makes no difference:

```
<dependency org="com.myco.fmwk.framework" name="framework-app-base" rev="0.0.+" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)" />
<dependency org="com.myco.fmwk.framework" name="framework-app-base" rev="0.0.+" m:classifier="test" conf="test->test(*)" />
```

How can we express this dependency?

Projects `myprj-common` and `framework-app-base` are not inside the same multi-project, so `myprj-common` can only depend upon the JARs generated by `framework-app-base`. In other words, it is not possible to add a `.dependsOn()` to the `build.sbt` (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up converting our dependency specifications to sbt syntax, inside build.sbt. To express the dependency on the test artifact, we use

`"com.myco.fmwk.framework" % "framework-app-base" % "0.0.+" % "compile->test;test->test" classifier "" classifier "test"`

which means that we add to the classpath `framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT` AND `framework-app-base-0.0.123-SNAPSHOT-test.jar.jar` respectively.

Maybe this can be done in a similar way using Ivy files, but we wanted to have all of our build specification expressed in a single format.